# Suppose $f, g : [0, 1] \to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous functions such that

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f, g : [0, 1] \to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous functions such that $\int_{0}^{1}f (x)dx = \int_{0}^{1}g(x)dx.$ Then

(i) $f(x)$ need not be equal to $g(x)$ for any $x \in [0, 1]$.

(ii) $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x \in [0, 1]$.

(iii) $f(x) = g(x)$ for infinitely many $x \in [0, 1]$.

(iv) $f(x) = g(x)$ for at least one $x \in [0, 1]$.

Consider $h=f-g$ so if $h(x)\ne 0$ at some point $x_0$ then by sign preserving property of continuous function it will contribute a non-zero area that will make the value of integral non-zero. I have no idea about the other parts, I have just read Riemann integral in an undergrad course.

Comment: You're right, (i) is not necessarily true. For (iii) try and come up *one* simple counterexample, which will then disprove (ii). Of course, if (i) is not true, then (iv) must be true, since it's the logical complement.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the functions $f(x)=x$ and $f(x)=1-x$ to eliminate two out of the four options.
 
To eliminate another *one* consider the function $h=f-g$ and show that $h$ cannot be nonzero in $[0,1]$ (in that case it will be positive on negative ...).